# How TS is not immediately convert an expression to be fully immutable?

Tags: typescript

As per the [`const assertion`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) in TS:

> Another thing to keep in mind is that const contexts don’t immediately
> convert an expression to be fully immutable.

I couldn't understand how TS is not able to make it immutable. Ideally it should throw error.

```
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
let foo = {
  name: "foo",
  contents: arr,
} as const;
foo.name = "bar"; // error!
foo.contents = []; // error!
foo.contents.push(5); // ...works!
```

If we add array value inside the `foo` object as literal then it is working:

```
let foo = {
  name: "foo",
  contents: [1, 2, 3, 4],
} as const;

foo.name = "bar"; // error!
foo.contents = []; // error!
foo.contents.push(5); // NOW THROW ERROR
```

How come this is working and what exactly does `don’t immediately convert and expression` mean?

Comment: `arr` is not a `readonly` array because you declared it separately. `as const` can't retroactively change the apparent type of previously declared variables. I'm not sure why you expect something else, can you explain?

Comment: when we declare an array `as const` then it should make its properties `readonly` as per the docs. Please correct me If I'm wrong

Comment: A property is readonly doesn't mean the object referenced by the property is readonly. Array is reference type, not primitive. `foo.contents` is like a pointer pointing to `arr`. You cannot change `foo.contents` to point to another object, but you can change the content of the object that it is already pointing to, if that object itself is not readonly.

Comment: Yes, but you didn't declare `arr` with `as const`. It's just a property of `foo`.  `as const` does not affect the types of existing variables.  `as const` only affects *literals*, and `arr` is a variable, not a literal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "immutability" applied by TypeScript is *shallow and type-level*. It doesn't enforce deep immutability, nor does it change the runtime JavaScript behavior. TypeScript's type system is designed to provide compile-time type checking and does not impact runtime behavior.

In your first example, `foo.name` becomes readonly because it's a direct property of `foo`. `foo.contents` is also readonly, preventing you from reassigning it to a different array. However, the contents of `arr` (and by extension `foo.contents` since it references `arr`) are not made deeply immutable by the const assertion. This means you can still modify `arr` (and thus `foo.contents`) by pushing elements into it or changing its elements if they were objects.

In your second example, `foo` and its properties are treated similarly at the top level. name is readonly, and contents cannot be reassigned. The difference arises because you've directly placed the array literal inside `foo`. When you do this, TypeScript infers the type of contents as a readonly tuple (`readonly [1, 2, 3, 4]`), which makes each element of the array also readonly. It might look like deep immutability, but it's actually the result of how TypeScript treats literals in a const context—it makes the elements of the array literal immutable because it treats them as a tuple.

You can make the first example throw as well, by just making the initial `arr` a `const` as well:

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4] as const;
let foo = {
  name: "foo",
  contents: arr,
} as const;
foo.name = "bar"; // error!
foo.contents = []; // error!
foo.contents.push(5); // error!
```